# Typescript compiled into wwwroot gives me "Duplicate identifier" error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm not sure if I've structured my project incorrectly or theres a setting I'm missing but I'm having a bit of an issue in visual studio 2015 with a "Duplicate identifier" error.

I have all of my typescript files in my ASP.NET 5 project and I have a grunt task that compiles them into javascript and places them inside of a scripts folder in the wwwroot folder. If I understand it correctly this is where the files that will be deployed should be.

The issue I have though is that when I run the grunt task and get the files outputted correctly, visual studio starts warning me inside my typescript files that I have duplicate identifiers. I would have thought that I'd be able to tell VS to ignore the wwwroot folder somewhere, but I can't seem to find any information on this.

Anyone had this before, or have I got the wrong end of the stick with how I should approach the structure?

Answer (score 1):

> visual studio starts warning me inside my typescript files that I have duplicate identifiers

This will *only* happen (baring any plugin like resharper) if you have *two* **TypeScript** files `declare`ing the same stuff. As you know compile outputs *JavaScript* so that is not the cause of this error. Fix: Remove the duplicate TypeScript.

**PS**

> I have a grunt task that compiles them into javascript and places them inside of a scripts folder in the wwwroot folder

Not the source of your error. But I would include the `*.js` files in the VS project using a glob `lib/**/*.js` as `wwwroot` is really for a particular IIS installation and not portable when you *publish* web apps.

Comment: I only get them when I run the grunt task, if I delete the generated files the error goes. I am running resharper though so I'll have to see if theres some option in there for this.

What do you mean by "using a glob lib/**/*.js as wwwroot"?

Comment: I had this problem when i used ./**/*.ts as 'scr' for my grunt-typescript task. I guess it enumerated the whole folder structure and included the .ts files from inside the grunt-typescript module as well. Changing the value of 'scr' to be more specific solved my problem. I leaving this here because this was the first answer that came up when i searched for the problem. Thanks!